# Which type of map content only road in offline mode and manage that with python?

Tags: python, maps, offline, osm.pbf

I used osm and osm.pbf, but I have some problems whit those.
I manage These types, with pyrosm library and got the driving network, but output of this, is very static.
In addition the roads don't have name.
I want use  just roads, with their name, in offline map.
Is there any map for this purpose ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want use map , for example Helsinki.osm.pbf in html or another framework , almost like google map or another Api and display that, without using internet connection. Just use my file (Helsinki) and display that like mapme? In what way I can show my map ( osm.pbf file), Java script ,  python library, or what? @Community